# DNS configuration question

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system

How can I configure DNS so that a domain is resolved into a local LAN address while in premise, and use the default DNS resolution elsewhere?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2):

Create an internal zone and records corresponding to the external zone. When clients are on the LAN, using the internal DNS server, they'll get DNS resolution for the internal zone. When clients are not on the LAN, using their ISP (or whichever) DNS server, they'll get DNS resolution for the external zone.

Answer (score 1):

You also may want to look into split-dns. This allows you to determine how DNS requests are handled and routed for internal and external users in your org. sharing the same DNS namespace.

Can you provide a scenario to clarify your question? The above suggestion may be overkill depending on what you are really trying to accomplish